# Using cookies for login php

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have an in-campus trading web site. The site is using sessions for login system. I wanted to add cookies to login system. However, since I have never used php cookies, for some reason system does not work. Actually without remembering (with using sessions) system works fine but it does not work with cookies.

Here my class before incrementing:

```
class LoggedUser{
public static function GetUserId(){
    return $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Id'];
}
public static function GetUserEmail(){
    return $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Email'];
}
public static function LogInUser(
        $user_id,
        $user_email,
    ){
        $_SESSION['LoggedUser'] = array();
        $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Email'] = $user_email;

}
public static function IsUserLogged(){
    $result = false;
    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedUser']))
        $result = true;
    return $result;
}
public static function LogOutUser(){
    unset($_SESSION['LoggedUser']);
}

}
```

After the incrementing:

```
class LoggedUser{
public static function GetUserId(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['LoggedUserId']))
        return $_COOKIE['LoggedUserId'];
    return $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Id'];
}
public static function GetUserEmail(){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['LoggedUserId']))
        return $_COOKIE['LoggedUserEmail'];
    return $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Email'];
}
public static function LogInUser(
        $user_id,
        $user_email,
        $remember
    ){
    if($remember == true){
        setcookie("LoggedUserId", $user_id, time()+60*60*24*30);
        setcookie("LoggedUserEmail", $user_email, time()+60*60*24*30);
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['LoggedUser'] = array();
        $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['LoggedUser']['Email'] = $user_email;
    }
}
public static function IsUserLogged(){
    $result = false;
    if(isset($_COOKIE['LoggedUserId']))
        $result = true;
    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedUser']))
        $result = true;
    return $result;
}
public static function LogOutUser(){
    unset($_COOKIE['LoggedUserId']);
    unset($_COOKIE['LoggedUserEmail']);
    unset($_SESSION['LoggedUser']);
}

}
```

Do you have any idea why system does not work with cookies?

Comment: WHY would you move login information to cookies instead of a session?

Comment: remembering user for a long time. Is there any other way? Or are you asking different question?

Comment: Is the login PHP file in a sub-directory? If so, add a starting directory in the set cookie command (`setcookie("LoggedUserId", $user_id, time()+60*60*24*30, "/");`)

Comment: When you use sessions, php will send a cookie to the client, so no need to use additional cookies, because you could store everything on the server !

Comment: @Robbie yes, in a sub directory. let me try ;)

Comment: @Robbie can you put it as an answer because it worked ;)

Comment: For other comments. Thanks for your advice I'll try another way for login with cookies.

Comment: @exculuber - have done, thanks. But the other advice (as in "why") was actually my first thought too. You only need to use cookies OR sessions, but not a hybrid. In some respects, they are very similar as sessions are most commonly controlled by cookies, so you can just add the additional data to the session. Sessions are then better as you transfer less data, but cookies better as they can last longer or different length than sessions (by default) and persist even when a server is rebooted. So use one, not both, depending on which suits your needs. Good luck.

Comment: This is extremely unsecure. A malicious user could simply just edit the cookie and pretend to be someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the login PHP file in a sub-directory?

If so, add a starting directory in the set cookie command

```
setcookie("LoggedUserId", $user_id, time()+60*60*24*30, "/");
```